# String replaceAll not working with string object

Tags: java

I have used below string operation but not able to understand why 1st case is not working.

Case - 1 :

```
String myString = new String("old String");
System.out.println(myString);
myString.replaceAll( "old", "new" );
System.out.println( myString );

//Output
old String
old String
```

Case - 2 :

```
String myString = new String("old String" );
System.out.println(myString);
myString = new String("new String");
System.out.println(myString);

//Output
old String
new String
```

Why case - 1 is working but case - 2 is not working?

Comment: String.replaceAll() returns a new instance of String with the changes. The original String is not changed because String is immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.replaceAll()` returns a new string with the specified replacement. You need to do:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll( "old", "new" );
```

Comment: Because this question has been answered so many times before, answering it again only to gain easy reputation is not cool. Especially that the answer is not that great: missing link to documentation for example.

Answer (score 0):

replaceAll method returns a String object. You must assign this back to myString or to another variable as strings are immutable.